# Linux-to-Windows: non-volatile const integral type

Tags: c++

I have some code, written on Linux, that i am attempting to compile in Windows, visual studio 2015.

In one of the Header files:

```
    #include <Eigen/Core>
    #include <Eigen/Geometry>
    #include <Eigen/StdVector>
    #include "transformable_vector.h"

    namespace nicp {

      template <int wCoordinate_>
        class HomogeneousVector4f : public Eigen::Vector4f {
      public:
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;

        static const float wCoordinate = wCoordinate_;

}
```

the lines:

```
 template <int wCoordinate_>
    class HomogeneousVector4f : public Eigen::Vector4f {
  public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;

    static const float wCoordinate = wCoordinate_;
```

are giving me this error:

```
Error   C2864   'nicp::HomogeneousVector4f<0>::wCoordinate': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type
```

I have tried removing the `const`, and replacing it with `constexpr`, but to the same result.

I have tried:

```
const float HomogeneousVector4f<wCoordinate_>::wCoordinate = wCoordinate_;
```

as well as:

```
 static constexpr float wCoordinate () { return wCoordinate_; }
```

and:

```
static float wCoordinate () { return wCoordinate_; }
```

EDIT: I have tried all the answers in the question marked as 'duplicate', to no avail. I believe the difference here is that this class is created with an int passed to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding "constexpr float HomogeneousVector4f:: wCoordinate;" to your .cpp file right after header include AND replace const with constexpr

Comment: Could you make a MCVE?  I cannot reproduce with [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a97548ff40b59f4) on MSVS 2015 or 2017.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I cannot add that under the includes, as the class is defined lower down. I have added more code to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Since `wCoordinate` is not of an integral type you need to define/initialize it "out of class".  Try putting `template<int wCoordinate_> const float HomogeneousVector4f<wCoordinate_>::wCoordinate = wCoordinate_` *after* the class definition for `HomogeneousVector4f`.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for your reply. I added this line, and see the same error. If I comment out `template <int wCoordinate_>`, intelsense complains